# Defining the file order for ImageMagick convert

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of `PNG` files named `foo<bar>.png` I wish to convert to TIF animation. `<bar>` is a number varies from 0 to 25 in leaps of five. ImageMagick place `foo5.png` last in the animation while it is supposed to be second. Is there a way, apart from renaming the file to `foo05.png` to place it in the right place?

Comment: Rename your images with leading zeros for the numbers, e.g.foo005.png. The wild card * reads the images in alphabetic order not numeric order. So the leading zeroes will cause your filenames to be be listed alphabetically when accessed by the wild card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just give the order of your PNG files as they should appear in the animation. Use:

```
foo0.png foo5.png foo10.png foo15.png foo20.png foo25.png
```

instead of

```
foo*.png
```

After all, it's only 6 different file names which should be easy enough to type:

```
convert                                                      \
  -delay 10                                                  \
   foo0.png foo5.png foo10.png foo15.png foo20.png foo25.png \
  -loop 0                                                    \
   animated.gif
```

Comment: @Yotam: Did you see my other answer? Is it not good enough for an 'upvote'?

Comment: It;s helpful to write such files with leading zeroes in the number part of the filename; then you can just say "*.png" and get them in the right order.  i.e., foo00.png foo05.png foo15.png foo20.png foo25.png.

Answer (score 16):

If you have more input images than are convenient enough to type (say, foo0..foo100.png), you could do this (on Linux, Unix and Mac OS X):

```
convert                                                  \
  -delay 10                                              \
   $(for i in $(seq 0 5 100); do echo foo${i}.png; done) \
  -loop 0                                                \
   animated.gif
```

Comment: Note that you can also use this to reverse the order of the GIF: $(seq 100 -5 0)

Comment: Note if you just want to reverse normal order you can use this method but replace sub command with `$(ls -r *.png)`.

Answer (score 14):

Simple and easy, list your images and sort them:

```sh
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 $(ls -1 *.png | sort -V) animated.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "find" with "sort":

```
convert -delay 10 $(find . -name "*.png" -print0 | sort -zV | xargs -r0 echo) -loop 0 animated.gif
```

Comment: Why use `find` instead of `ls`? Why `xargs`? See my answer for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier than ls and sort is to use the built-in -v option of ls:

`` convert -delay 10 -loop 0 `ls -v *.png` animated.gif ``

with `` `...` `` being executed instead of interpreted as string.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you know a bit of python, then you can easily leverage the help of it from python shell.

Hit up python shell by typing `python` in your terminal. And apply following magic spells-

```
# Suppose your files are like 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg etc. upto 100.jpeg
files = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    files.append('{}.jpeg'.format(i))
command = 'convert -delay 10 {} -loop 0 animated.gif'.format(' '.join(files))
from subprocess import call
call(command, shell=True)
```

Your job should be done!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do something like:

```
convert $(ls -v *.png) animated.gif
```