# Build sorted and annotated pdf from images

Tags: image, bash, pdf

I am trying to build a `pdf` from a set of image files in the same folder from the bash. So far I've got this code:

```
ls *.jpg | sort > files.txt
ls *.jpg | sort | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\ data_graphs.pdf/' | xargs convert -gravity North -annotate @files.txt
rm files.txt
```

This code collapses the image, but they are not properly sorted, and the annotation is the same for every image (the first one in the list).

Here is the `ls * jpg |sort` output for reference.

```
$ ls *.jpg | sort 
01.20.2014_A549_void.jpg
01.20.2014_EPOR_full_sorter.jpg
01.20.2014_EPOR_trunc_sorter.jpg
01.20.2014_WTGFP_sorter.jpg
01.27.2014_A549_void.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_full_I10412.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_full_sorter.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_trunc_I10412.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_trunc_sorter.jpg
01.27.2014_WTGFP_I10412.jpg
01.27.2014_WTGFP_sorter.jpg
02.03.2014_A549_void.jpg
02.03.2014_EPOR_full_sorter.jpg
02.03.2014_EPOR_trunc_sorter.jpg
02.03.2014_WTGFP_sorter.jpg
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913292/how-to-sort-input-png-files-in-imagemagick

Answer (score 1):

How about this, no need generate the temporary file `files.txt`

```
convert -gravity North -annotate `ls *.jpg | sort -t . -k3.3n -k1.1n -k2.2n ` data_graphs.pdf
```

According the comments, these jpg files have time-stamp in file name (MM-DD-YYYY), I updated the sort command.

#### another way, convert each jpg file to pdf first, then use pdftk to merge them, I used pdftk for long years and know the software can do the job easily. Here is the pdftk server url : pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server.

Below script will convert jpg file to pdf one by one

```
for file in *jpg
do
  convert -gravity North -annotate "$file" "$file".pdf
done
```

Then run the pdftk command, if you have hugh number of pdf.  With pdftk, you can merge every 10~20 into a small pdf, then merge the small pdf to final pdf. For example:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf output m1.pdf
```

then you will get mXXX.pdf files, then run the pdftk again:

```
pdftk m1.pdf m2.pdf m3.pdf output final.pdf
```

Comment: The output is still both unsorted images in the pdf and the same annotation for every graph.

Comment: Could you please show me the command output `ls *.jpg | sort`, if the files are sorted or not. Second, please review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339330/defining-the-file-order-for-imagemagick-convert, and check if you can get any helps

Comment: Here is what you requested:

`$ ls *.jpg | sort
01.20.2014_A549_void.jpg
01.20.2014_EPOR_full_sorter.jpg
01.20.2014_EPOR_trunc_sorter.jpg
01.20.2014_WTGFP_sorter.jpg
01.27.2014_A549_void.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_full_I10412.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_full_sorter.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_trunc_I10412.jpg
01.27.2014_EPOR_trunc_sorter.jpg
01.27.2014_WTGFP_I10412.jpg
01.27.2014_WTGFP_sorter.jpg
02.03.2014_A549_void.jpg
02.03.2014_EPOR_full_sorter.jpg
02.03.2014_EPOR_trunc_sorter.jpg
02.03.2014_WTGFP_sorter.jpg`

There are too many files to type them by hand

Comment: I updated your comments in your original question, and provide a new sort command `sort -t . -k3.3n -k1.1n -k2.2n`, can you try now?

Comment: I had to stop that command, after 1 minute it just kept executing.

Comment: Can we think another way, convert each jpg file to pdf first, then use pdftk to merge them, I used pdftk for long years and know the software can do the job easily. Here is the url : http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

Comment: I got an error message when trying the solution.
convert: option requires an argument `-annotate' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/669.