# How to sort input PNG files in ImageMagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I am making an animated GIF file using following command:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png animated.gif
```

But, the problem happens in the order of *.png.

My PNG files are like 1.png, 2.png, ... 100.png.

In the resulting animated GIF, the order of frames are like: 1.png, 10. png, 100.png, 2.png ...

I want that in the resultant GIF the snapshot are in order like 1,2,3 ... 100.

Comment: Just rename your images with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try `sort`:

```
$ ls | sort -V
1.png
2.png
10.png
100.png
```

So ultimately:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 $(ls *.png | sort -V) animated.gif
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work on Mac OSX 10.12.6 (sort: invalid option -- V)

Comment: @BenClayton Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394536)

Answer (score 1):

This little script will rename your files for you with leading zeroes - try it on a COPY of your files first:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}; do
   [ -f "$i.jpg" ] && echo mv "$i.jpg" $(printf "%04d.jpg" $i)
done
```

It looks for JPEG files from 1.jpg through 1000.jpg and if any exist, it renames then with up to 3 leading zeroes till the number part is 4 digits wide.

If you save it as `renamer`, you will then run

```
chmod +x renamer    # just do this once to make it executable
./renamer           # do this any time you want the whole directory of JPEGs renamed
```

Remove the word `echo` if you see and like what it is going to do, then run it again.

**Sample output**

```
mv 1.jpg 0001.jpg
mv 99.jpg 0099.jpg
mv 102.jpg 0102.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rename** your images with **leading zeroes** like:

```
001.png, 002.png, 003.png,......099.png,100.png.
```

And it will work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

The glob operator (*)  sorts the result list by comparing texts. So renaming the files 1.png, 2.png ... to  001.png, 002.png should work.